# Creating an object with values of JSON path

Tags: json, object, i18next

I implemented i18n with useTranslation and tried to make it easier for json path to be written.

```
JSON
{
    "userInfo":{
        "name": "Name",
        "lastname": "Last Name"
    },
    "sideMenu:{
        "home":"Home"
    }
}
```

So now when I try to access translated text I go

> t("userInfo.name", "Name")
> I tried to make a function that will recursively call it self and create the object like this

```
object = {
    userInfo: {
        name: {
            key:"userInfo.name",
            value:"Name"
        },
        lastname: {
            key:"userInfo.lastname",
            value:"Last name"
        },
    },
    sideMenu: {
        home: {
            key:"sideMenu.home",
            value:"Home"
        }
    }
}
```

so now I could access like this

> t(object.userInfo.name.key, object.userInfo.name.value)

I tried using entries and fromEntries function but I simply cant get hold of the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with a recursive function so now, no matter the number of nested objects function will return a new object with key and value items.

You can see working snippet with json file i used for the project.

```js
let en = {
    "userInfo":{
        "name": "Name",
        "lastname": "Last Name",
        "gender": "Gender",
        "age": "Age",
        "location": "Location",
        "address": "Address",
        "city": "City",
        "login": "Login",
        "about": "About"
    },

    "comboBox": {
        "loading": "Loading...",
        "loadmore": "Load More"
    },

    "error": {
        "errormsg": "Ooops, it seems you are not authenticated to see this...",
        "errormsgsub": "Get back and try again",
        "errorbtn": "Back to Safety",
        "alertmsg": "You should login first!"
    },
    
    "sideMenu": {
        "home": "Home",
        "logout": "Logout",
        "croatian": "Croatian",
        "english": "English",
        "hello": "Hello"
    },
    
    "loadingPage": {
        "load": "Loading...",
        "loadsub": "Please wait"
    }
}

function languageRecursion(data, key){
    if (typeof data === 'object') {
        return Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(data).map(([ikey, value]) => {
                return [ikey, languageRecursion(value, key ? `${key}.${ikey}` : ikey)];
            })
        );
    }

    return { key: key, value: data };
}

let locale = languageRecursion(en)


console.log("path",locale.userInfo.about.key)
console.log("value", locale.userInfo.about.value)
```

With this working now you can call languages with i18next useTranslation hook faster and easier.

```
t(locale.userInfo.name.key)
```